# Jprompt show input with undefined?

Tags: jquery, prompt

I am using jPrompt with input box but it is showing me undefined.

```
var reason = jPrompt('Are you sure to delete','add reason',Confirmation',function(del){
console.log(reason);
// output for this 'undefined';
///ajax code
})
```

i dont know what's wrong in my code.Not getting any error for my code.

Comment: What plugin are you using here and what is the link for it?

Comment: abeautifulsite jquery alert plugins